# Trying to mock delay in API response: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, mocking, es6-promise

In my React app I'm trying to fake a delay in mock API response

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

```
createDraft() {
  // Post to Mock API
  const newDraft = {
    name: this.state.draftName,
    created_by: this.props.user,
    created: getDate()
  };

  /* ERROR HERE */
  this.props.create(newDraft).then((res) => {
    console.log(' res', res);
    // Display loading spinner while waiting on Promise

    // Close modal and redirect to Draft Summary view
    this.props.closeModal();
  });
}
```

**The action:**

```
export const create = newDraft => dispatch => all()
  .then(() => setTimeout(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: CREATE,
      newDraft
    });
    return 'Draft created!';
  }, 2000))
  .catch(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_ERROR,
      payload: apiErrors.BAD_REQUEST
    });
  });
```

**Connected area:**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  create: (newDraft) => { dispatch(create(newDraft)); }
});

export const CreateDraftModalJest = CreateDraftModal;

export default connect(cleanMapStateToProps([
  'user'
]), mapDispatchToProps)(CreateDraftModal);
```

### Also tried this with same result

```
function DelayPromise(t) {
  return new Promise(((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, t);
  }));
}

export const create = newDraft => dispatch => all()
  .then(DelayPromise(2000))
  .then(() => {
    console.log('created called', newDraft);
    dispatch({
      type: CREATE,
      newDraft
    });
  })
  .then(() => 'Draft created!')
  .catch(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_ERROR,
      payload: apiErrors.BAD_REQUEST
    });
  });
```

Comment: Looks like `all` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: Are you sure that your action creator is being called with dispatch in your component? Are you using connect's mapDispatchToProps correctly?

Comment: Yes the action is being called, I got a log to work in the setTimeout, posting new code I just tried too.

Comment: `.then(DelayPromise(2000))` is not correct.  It would need to be `.then(() => DelayPromise(2000))`.  You pass `.then()` a function reference that it can call later, not a promise.

Comment: I just fixed that, the delay in the Action creator works cause I see the state update, just the .then in the Component doesn't work and I can't close the modal. (same error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your `this.props.create()` action creator is not bound to dispatch, and therefore not returning the promise as expected.

Are you using `react-redux` connect() properly?

EDIT:

Your mapDispatchToProps is not returning the promise. Do this instead:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  create: (newDraft) => dispatch(create(newDraft)),
});
```

Comment: You're mapDispatchToProps is not returning the promise..see my edit!

Comment: That was it! Thanks :D 1 min!